# MongoDB morphia query with a modulo operation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, morphia, nosql

I am trying to convert following operation from MongoShell to Morphia wrapped mongodb query.

any help would be appreciated :

```
db.ObjectMap.find(
    {
        user: {
            $mod : [10/* desired divisor*/,
   2/*desired remainder */]
        },
        items : {
            $elemMatch : {
                endTime : {
                $gt : 111111

                $lt : 222222
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I have gone this far, but I am unable to find a good way to use modulo operator on the field.

```
Query<ObjectMap> query = ds
            .createQuery(ObjectMap.class)
                .field(ObjectMap.FIELD_TIME).greaterThanOrEq(startTime)
                .field(ObjectMap.FIELD_TIME).lessThanOrEq(endTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was just filed this weekend:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/517

-- Update  9/10

I just pushed changes to implement this filter.  It will be included in the upcoming 0.104 release.  If you'd like to test it early, you can build master and use the generated jar.

-- Update 9/12

Version 0.104 with this fix has just been released:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/releases/tag/0.104

Comment: Yup. We are hoping for it. :)